# Where is nelem.h? (for OpenSSL)

Tags: openssl, include

I am trying to build OpenSSL from source as downloaded from git://git.openssl.git. The compile fails because it cannot open "nelem.h. I've searched for it in the entire downloaded repo and in all the MSVC 2019 include directories but no luck. Where is that beast?

Comment: It's in include/internal/nelem.h in the OpenSSL repo. But you should not be seeing a compile error. What are your build steps? Are you following the instructions in INSTALL.md?

Comment: I searched the entire cloned repo but it wasn't there.  But I did find it with a Google search. I have posted it as an answer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by Google search. I manually created it as below

```
// nelem.h
#ifndef OSSL_INTERNAL_NELEM_H
# define OSSL_INTERNAL_NELEM_H
# define OSSL_NELEM(x)    (sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0]))
#endif
```

UPDATE 3/9/21
Matt Caswell was right: Today I found it in **include/internal/nelem.h**